# How to get active directory user name without domain name?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am getting this in my SharePoint output  in script editor. executions as follows:

```
 i:0#.w|iscsharepoint\administrator
```

The code for this is as follows for this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetLoggedInUserName()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = context.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
 alert(currentUser.get_loginName());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Now I am trying to get it this excution.

```
"Hi Administrator"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the username manually, like so:

```
var name = currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1];
alert("Hi " + name);
```

You can also retrieve the user's actual name instead of their login  name:

```
var name = currentUser.get_title();
alert("Hi " + name);
```

Comment: Hey 2 nd work worked for me aswome @ Thriggle Thanks... :->